# D3 LineGraph Circles Remove Overlap && Sort dates

Tags: d3.js, geometry, margin, overlap, linegraph

http://www.fabieno.com/conanbatt/index.html

Circles are overlapping, and because they have tooltips. This is a bit of a pain. How can I modify this to stop the overlap?

Also, how do I format the dates in to a way I would prefer to see them? For instance vertical and YYYY/dd/mm

https://github.com/FabienO/OpenKaya-1/tree/master/widgets/rank_graph

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the overlapping circles -- assuming you'd like their position on the X-axis to accurately represent the time of day their game took place -- as I see it you have two options.

In chart.js:

1) make the graph wider:

```
// line 101
var w = $(that.html).parent().width() || 500; //Sometimes this is 0, dont know why.
```

2) make the radius of each circle smaller.

```
// line 120
var pointRadius = 2;
```

As a bonus, I suggest adding a fill color to each circle:

```
// line 244, replace circles.enter() with the following
circles
    .enter()
        .append('svg:circle')
            .attr('class', 'data-point')
            .style('opacity', 1e-6)
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .attr('cy', function() { return y(0) })
            .attr('r', function() { return (data.length <= maxDataPointsForDots) ? pointRadius : 0 })
            // On hover, fill the circle
            .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
              circles.filter(function(p) {
                return d === p;
              })
              .style('fill', 'steelblue');
            })
            // Clear the fill
            .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
              circles.filter(function(p) {
                return d === p;
              })
              .style('fill', 'white');
            })
        .transition()
        .duration(transitionDuration)
            .style('opacity', 1)
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.value) });
```

Regarding the date format for the X-axis labels:

```
// line ~124
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(h - margin * 2).tickPadding(10).ticks(7).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%Y/%d/%m'));
```

To rotate them:

```
// line ~151
// x ticks and labels
if (!xAxisGroup) {
    xAxisGroup = svg.append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'xTick')
        .call(xAxis);
    xAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(-210, 140) rotate(-45)');
}
else {
    t.select('.xTick').call(xAxis);
}
```

I forked your repo and opened a pull against it so you can see all the changes at once: https://github.com/FabienO/OpenKaya-1/pull/1